# Image uploading to server in android

Tags: java, android

I had some problem before which I solved. Thanks a lot to everyone who replied to the queries.

I am trying to upload image from my android application to server (Servelet). I have also emulated the SD Card which contains one jpeg image.

I have been able to make connection with the server and get some message back. But so far I have not been able to retrieve the image on the server. I get error msg on the server. I am using multipart option. The code are as follows. Plz have a look and let me know what wrong I am doing.

**ANDROID SIDE**

```
     String path="http://10.0.2.2:8080/ImageLocalizer/Localize";
        String pathToFile="/sdcard/building.jpg";
        text1.setText(path);

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
        try
        {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToFile) );

        URL url = new URL(path);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs & Outputs
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        // Enable POST method
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",  "multipart/form-data");
        connection.setRequestProperty("FileName", "building.jpg");

        DataOutputStream outputStream =new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream());
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        fileInputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        text1.setText(path);

        BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( connection.getInputStream() ) );

        String response="",msg="";
        while ( (response = in.readLine()) != null ) {
            msg+=response;
        }
        text2.setText(msg);
    }        
    catch (Exception ex)
     {}

    }
```

**SERVELET SIDE**

```
   doPost()
    {
            System.out.println("RUNNING");
             InputStream in = request.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
                String line;

                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                out.println("Image copied !!");
                out.close();
                try  
                {  
                        PrintWriter out1=response.getWriter();  
                        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();  
                        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);  
                        String s[]=new String[30];  
                        byte i=0;  
                        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);  
                        if(isMultipart)  
                        {  
                            List items=upload.parseRequest(request);      
                            Iterator iterator=items.iterator();  
                            while(iterator.hasNext())  
                            {  
                                FileItem fitem=(FileItem)iterator.next();  
                                if(!fitem.isFormField())  
                                {  
                                    StringBuffer s2=new StringBuffer(fitem.getName());                    
                                    if(s2!=null && s2.length()>0)  
                                    {  
                                        File fl=new File("H:\\abcd.jpg");  
                                        fitem.write(fl);  
                                    }  
                                }  
                                if(fitem.isFormField())  
                                {  
                                    s[i]=fitem.getString();  
                                    i++;  
                                }  
                            }  

                        }  

                }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}  


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think the body of your request is formatted corrected as multi part form data. The body should contain several different delimited sections, with each section containing the filename and encoding of that section. See the following URL for an example:

http://chxo.com/be2/20050724_93bf.html

If you're only posting one file at a time I would remove the multi part form data header and just post the contents of the file as the request body.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, but you could send the image as bytes and read those bytes directly on the server. This would mean that you're not sending a multipart form though, so you should remove that header.